# Unable To Create a New Project with Angular

Tags: angular

Please can anyone help?, recently I have been trying to create a new angular project on my local computer but it has been giving the same error, I even tried reinstalling angular again but it still didn't work.

I even tried reinstalling angular again but it still didn't work.

ng new MyProject and then I get this Error:

> npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near
>   '...-\r\nVersion: OpenPGP'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-10-24T21_30_15_950Z-debug.log
>   Package install failed, see above.
>   This Is The Error From The Debug Log:

```
2330 verbose stack     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
2330 verbose stack     at parseJson (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\json-parse-better-errors\index.js:7:17)
2330 verbose stack     at C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\body.js:96:50
2330 verbose stack     at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
2330 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
2331 verbose cwd C:\Users\User\ALCProject
2332 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
2333 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--quiet"
2334 verbose node v12.13.0
2335 verbose npm  v6.12.0
2336 error Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...8f34","tarball":"http'
2337 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Did you try to write a project name with lowercasse for example myproject ?
And please paste the error from the debug log.

Comment: Try `npm cache clean --force` then `npm install -g @angular/cli`
 Source: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/19072

Comment: @ZhuniqiA I just tried writing the project name in lowercase, but still the same error. I have also Pasted the error from the debug log

Comment: This looks to me like a broken download/install ...

Comment: @yms I've tried that but it is still the same error

Comment: What is your node.js, npm and angular versions?

Comment: @Anna `node: v12.13.0 npm: 6.12.0 angular: 8.3.14`

Comment: Possibly this is not the reason but be sure the folder where you execute `ng new my-app` has no any file .json

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
**First**

```
npm cache clean --force
```

**Second**

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

And let me know if it works for you ?

If this doesn't work then try like this.

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean --force
```

To verify: ng --version /* You will get the error message, then u have uninstalled */

Using following commands to re-install :

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```